# Zsh command history completion

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

How to have case insensitive in retrieving completion of command history in Zsh ?

did put `setopt NOCASEGLOB` in ~/.zshrc but has nothing for help

how is the correct way to do?

Comment: What do you mean by *history completion*? Is that the history incremental search backward/forward as bound on Ctrl+R/S in emacs mode?